# Is there way to create foreach for sql code with array data

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I got one query that takes data about users.

I need to make a 2nd query for each of these users.

I am getting data just for the first user. (with the second query)

First query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tipuser WHERE permissions = '0'");
$ah = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Also when i do for each($query as $x) and inside that i echo first and last name it shows all, when i do the same with $ah it doesn't show anything.

Then I got these variables:

```
$firstname = $ah['firstname'];
$lastname = $ah['lastname'];
```

Second query:

```
$sqlwork = mysqli_query($conn, 
        "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS Monthyear, 
                count(projekt) AS celkem, 
                SUM(projekt = 0) AS tipsport,  
                SUM(projekt = 1) AS slavia, 
                SUM(projekt = 2) AS bet 
        FROM zapasy 
        WHERE komentator1 = '$firstname $lastname' 
           OR komentator2 = '$firstname $lastname' 
        GROUP BY Monthyear");
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the array but I can't find it.
I am thankful for any help.

UPDATE:
this is how to display it on site:

```
         <?php foreach($query AS $usersall) {?>
           <table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered" style="border-top: 0px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);">


    <thead style="color:black; background-color: hsla(0,0%,71%,1.00); border-top: 0px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Měsíc</th>
            <th scope="col">Zápasů</th>
            <th scope="col">BET</th>
            <th scope="col">TipSport</th>
            <th scope="col">Slavia</th>
            <th scope="col">Brutto</th>
            <th scope="col">Daň</th>
            <th scope="col">Netto</th>
            <th scope="col">Zaplaceno</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while ($tip = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlwork)) {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['Monthyear'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?=$tip['celkem']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['bet']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['tipsport']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$tip['slavia']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                        $betx = $tip['bet']*$bet1cena['cena'];
                        $tipx = $tip['tipsport']*$tipcena['cena']; 
                        $slax = $tip['slavia']*$slaviacena['cena']; 
                        $celkem = $betx+$tipx+$slax;
                        echo "$celkem Kč";
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                        if($user['fakturuje'] == 0){
                            $dan = $celkem*0.15;
                            echo "$dan Kč";

                        }else{
                            echo "0 Kč";
                        }                                   
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                   $netto = $celkem-$dan;
                   echo "$netto Kč"; 
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  sorry, i said it wrong, i am just not getting data from 2nd query for rest of the users.

Comment: Check what `$firstname` and `$lastname` are and then try the same query in something like phpmyadmin.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @NigelRen it works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You are going to have to show us more of the PHP code for us to be able to see what you are doing and be able to help you

Comment: If either the $firstname or $lastname values has an apostrophe in it, it will mess up the query string.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok i added everything.

Comment: @MER I don't use any apostrophe

Comment: Sidenotes: 1. Please use english names for columns and table names. You never know who will be working with your code in future. 2. It's not good idea to search `zapasy` by name `komentator1` and `komentator2`. Those columns should have ID of users from `tipuser`. 3. It might be a good idea to have another table joining `zapasy` and `tipuser`so you can have any number of `komentator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not completely clear from your question I think you are getting multiple rows from your first query and wanting to run the second query on each row returned by the first query

This is one way, I have taken the liberty of using a prepared query for the second one, this should remove any SQL Injection issues and also any problems with Last Names like `O'Toole` (the apostrophe issue). It also means you only need compile the query once, but can run it with new parameters as many times as you need.

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tipuser WHERE permissions = '0'");

$q2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%b %Y') AS Monthyear, 
                count(projekt) AS celkem, 
                SUM(projekt = 0) AS tipsport,  
                SUM(projekt = 1) AS slavia, 
                SUM(projekt = 2) AS bet 
        FROM zapasy 
        WHERE komentator1 = ? 
           OR komentator2 = ? 
        GROUP BY Monthyear");

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($q2);

while ($ah = mysqli_fetch_array($q1) ) {

    // make the full name field
    $name = $ah['firstname'] . ' ' . $ah['lastname'];

    // bind those values to the prepared query
    $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $name, $name );
    $stmt2->execute();

    // present the results of this query
    // however you like
}
```

Comment: yep I want that, but when i replace my code with this and rename variables it doesn't work. i get just white screen without content

Comment: White screen? Try enabling all error reporting so you can see what may be the syntax explosion. Add `ini_set('display_startup_errors', true); ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I think you meant for the `$q2` var to be set to the SQL string - you currently have it set to the result of the query (2nd line of code). That is: `$q2 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT..."` instead of `$q2 = mysqli_query(...`

Comment: Marek, sorry I had a foolish typo in my original code. It is corrected now.